# Server DB usage

Tags: mysql, gwt, vaadin, rpc

I've been trying to create 2 proof of concept applications with gwt and vaadin.

I started with gwt:

I was astonished by the idea off me debugging the client side in eclipse :)
The same reason I couldn't open a connection in mysql. in my gwt project (its client side DUH?!)

When I started working with vaadin I saw the following weirdness:
I could open a connection of mysql and inject the results into the containers.
Now that's weird?! how can I do mysql connection in the client? and how come I don't need an rpc for the db info to be transferred to the client?

I'm sure im missing something here. any help?

Comment: In GWT you can not create a connection to a database on the client side. You have to write a service - normally RCP - to call the server. On the serverside, it is quite easy to connect to a database. Create DTOs to transport your data to the client and use the Editor Framework to fill your data into the widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin is basically gwt with server-side business logic.
The containers work on server side, the results are then displayed with gut components.